# Hibernate- @OnetoMany with Where clause on Collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, hibernate-mapping

In my One-to-Many and Many-to-One bi-directional relation, I want execute the following sql-

```
select * from user_credential c 
join user_profile p on c.login_id = p.login_id
join user_address a on p.address_id = a.address_id
where p.profile_id = 1
```

But, I'm getting the result of the sql-

```
select * from user_credential c 
join user_profile p on c.login_id = p.login_id
join user_address a on p.address_id = a.address_id
where p.credential_id = 1
```

The hibernate entity details-

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user_credential")
    public class UserCredential implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2839071606927921689L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "login_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
        private int login_id = 0;

        @Column(name = "password", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
        private String password = null;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "login_id", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<UserProfile> profiles = null;
//getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profile")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5765280899633539336L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "profile_id", length = 10, insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int profile_id = 0;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "login_id", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
    private UserCredential login_id = null;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 20, insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
    private String name = null;

    @Column(name = "age", length = 3, insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
    private byte age = 0;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile_id", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserAddress> address = null;

//getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_address")
public class UserAddress extends BaseTable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5036341911955664992L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "address_id", length = 10, insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int address_id = 0;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
    private UserProfile profile_id = null;

    @Column(name = "state", length = 20, insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
    private String state = null;

    @Column(name = "city", length = 20, insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
    private String city = null;
//getters/setters
}
```

HQL:

```
select credential from UserCredential credential
join credential.profiles profile
where  profile.profile_id = 1
```

I'm not understanding, why hibernate is filtering the data on parent id and also, how my required sql will be executed. I'm using hibernate 4.3.8

Please tell, if any other information is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the query like this:

```
select distinct c 
from Profile p
join p.login_id c
where p.profile_id = 1
```

The duplicates are removed and joining from `Child` to `Parent` might help you with your problem.

Comment: This approach is useful, unless I add join and condition on the last child **UserAddress**. Also, `join p.login_id c` is not required in this case, since it will definitely make a _join_ with **UserProfile** and will fetch an unique result. The `distinct` is also not required for the same reason. However, I'm getting a ClassCastException between **UserCredential** and **UserProfile**, while using the above query.

Comment: You get a ClassCastException because the query returns a List of Profiles while you didn't change the previous List of Credentials.

Comment: I didn't debug that. It was actually returning the a single record of Credential, not Profile, as you're fetching _distinct c_. But still the result is same. If you need any other information, please tell.